# if there a way to pass python tkinter scrollbar drag and press events through lambda function?

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I have this line of code which is part of python program code I am working on:

```
scroll_horz.configure(command=lambda movement, value, unit, table= purchase_table: scrol_handler(movement, value, unit, table)
```

`scroll_horz` is a scrollbar widget and `purchase_table` is a treeview widget.

the problem is when I press scrollbar arrow every thing goes will because the return of event in this case are are 3 component "scroll", "1", "units" which are matching the objects in lambda
but and here is the problem when I drag the slider an error occurs (() missing 1 required positional argument: 'unit') because the event returns 2 components "moveto" and 0.0589265

How can I override this issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> if there a way to pass python tkinter scrollbar drag and press events through lambda function?

Yes, of course. The scrollbars call a function, and that function can be anything as long as it accepts the proper arguments.

However, your function needs to be prepared to accept all of the different forms of inputs that the scrollbar might receive. As documented, the scrollbar command can be called with the following arguments:

- **moveto**, *fraction*
- **scroll**, *number*, **units**
- **scroll**, *number*, **pages**

Your code is assuming it always is passed three arguments, and thus it throws an error when it receives the first variation with only two arguments.

Your lambda function needs to be able to accept the two-argument variation. You can do that by using `*args` for the parameters that the scrollbar sends, and then dealing with the variations within your function.

```
scroll_horz.configure(command=lambda *args, table= purchase_table: scrol_handler(*args, table)
```

Your `scrol_handler` function can then examine `args` to see if the first word is `scroll` or `moveto` and do the appropriate thing. Or, just pass all of the arguments straight to the `yview` command of the text widget.

```
def scrol_handler(*args, foobar):
    text.yview(*args)
    print("args:", args, "foobar:", foobar)
```